Outlook Error: LDAP Query Exceeds Limit When Sending Email Using win32com
Description:
I'm working with the win32com.client module in Python to send emails via Outlook. I saw that the email is instantiated as a CDispatch object. However, I encounter an LDAP error when calling the Send() method.
Error Details:
I receive the following error message in console:
(-2147352567, 'Ausnahmefehler aufgetreten.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Outlook kennt mindestens einen Namen nicht.', None, 0, -2147467259), None)

Additionally, a pop-up message from Microsoft Outlook appears:

Microsoft LDAP-Verzeichnis
Die Anzahl der vom LDAP-Verzeichnisserver für diesen Suchvorgang gefundenen Einträge überschreitet das von Ihnen vorgegebene Limit.

Translated: "The number of entries found by the LDAP directory server for this search exceeds the limit you set."
Current Setup:
Here’s a simplified version of the Python code I’m using:
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import CDispatch

def setup_mailbox(shared_mailbox_display_name: str):
    outlook = client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    mailbox_kaffee = None

    namespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    stores = namespace.Stores
    for store in stores:
        print(store.DisplayName)
        if store.DisplayName == shared_mailbox_display_name:
            mailbox_kaffee = store
            break

    if mailbox_kaffee is None:
        raise Exception(f"Shared mailbox '{shared_mailbox_display_name}' not found.")
    return mailbox_kaffee

def send_email(body: str,
               _mailbox: CDispatch,
               receiver: str,
               display_name: str):
    mail_folder = mailbox.GetDefaultFolder(6)  # 6 is for email folder
    email = mail_folder.Items.Add(0)  # Add an email item
    email.Subject = "Test Email"
    email.HTMLBody = body
    email.SentOnBehalfOfName = display_name
    email.Recipients.Add(receiver)

    email.Save()
    email.Send()  # Error occurs here

# Simplified call to the function
mailbox_display_name = "test"
mailbox = setup_mailbox(mailbox_display_name)
send_email("<html><body>Hello</body></html>", mailbox, "receiver@example.com", "Sender Display Name")

Environment:

Python 3.10
pywin32 version 306
Microsoft Outlook (Version 2016)

Question:
How can I resolve this error or prevent Outlook from performing an LDAP query that exceeds the result limit when sending an email via Python? or maybe I can fix it by setting up something in outlook manually?
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

It is solved. The problem was simple. Some email addresses are not valid, which causes the problem. Adding a validation of email address has solved the problem.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
